# I have issue to retrive post thumbnail with rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

i have two site. main site and blog site. both of them are wordpress. i want show my latest post from
blog site to main site. but I have issue to retrieve post thumbnail.
all thing is OK except Thumbnail.

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post['id']), 'thumbnail')
```

retrive false.

```
function display_latest_blog_posts() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering

    // Replace with the URL of your blog site
    $blog_site_url = 'http://www.blog.domain.com';

    // Get the latest blog posts using WP REST API
    $response = wp_remote_get($blog_site_url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3');
    $posts = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    if (!empty($posts)) {
        $posts = json_decode($posts, true);

        echo '<div class="latest-blog-posts">';
        
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo '<div class="post">';
            echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $post['title']['rendered'] . '</h2>';
            echo '<p class="post-date">' . date('F j, Y', strtotime($post['date'])) . '</p>';
            
            if (has_post_thumbnail($post['id'])) {
                $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post['id']), 'thumbnail')[0];
                echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail_url . '" class="post-thumbnail" alt="' . $post['title']['rendered'] . '">';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
        }
        
        echo '</div>';
    }

    $output = ob_get_clean(); // Get the buffered content
    return $output;
}
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

i have two site. main site and blog site. both of them are wordpress. i want show my latest post from
blog site to main site. but I have issue to retrieve post thumbnail.
all thing is OK except Thumbnail.

Comment: "have issue" is not a useful problem description, we cannot work anything out from that. Be more specific, and include the results of the debugging you've done so far to try and narrow down the issue. See also [ask]

Comment: All the other post data you fetched via the Rest API of the other site - but `get_post_thumbnail_id` and `wp_get_attachment_image_src` are operating within the "scope" of your current site. It is not really clear what your setup is here, when you say you have "two sites" - are those completely separate WP installations, or is it a multi-site setup?

Comment: yes. completely separate. how can I send URL of thumbnail from the blog Site